# Get actual size photoURL via Google Signin?

Tags: authentication, flutter, google-signin, imageurl

I am trying Google Signin method in flutter and getting google photoURL via `user.photoURL` which returns me this url `https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-cALD0EpWqls/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAARs/RaQzFwo3fzo/s96-c/photo.jpg` but its size is 96x96, I googled this issue and found that by adding the attribute of `sz` at the end of url, the size can be changed e.g. `https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-cALD0EpWqls/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAARs/RaQzFwo3fzo/s96-c/photo.jpg?sz=200` , Although I can change this size but how can I get Actual size of picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the only parameters provided by their APIs for Image handling before retrieving:

```
https://developers.google.com/people/image-sizing
```

So I think the simplest method to get the full profile picture by setting the profile picture dimension yourself or try this trick by setting either the width or height to some arbitrarily large number, and it should returns the max size they have:

```
https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-cALD0EpWqls/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAARs/RaQzFwo3fzo/s96-c/photo.jpg?sz=9999
```

Answer (score 0):

If you delete `s96-c/` fragment form url you will get original photo, so in this example your url should look like that: `https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-cALD0EpWqls/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAARs/RaQzFwo3fzo/photo.jpg`
It's bit of hack though